# "value does not fall within the expected range" when running excel workbook

Tags: excel, visual-studio, vsto, ms-office

I'm running an excel workbook that leverages a VSTO file, but when opening the workbook I get the following error

```
Name: 
From: file:///C:/Users/Daniel/Documents/Twitter Analytics/TwitterAnalytics.vsto

************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.VSTOEENativeMethods.GetValidCompatibleFramework(String compatibleFrameworkXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.CompatibleFrameworksValidation.ParseFirstValidFramework(String compatibleFrameworksXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.OfficeAddInDeploymentManager.OnAddInManifestsDownloaded(AddInManifestsDownloadedArgs args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.RaiseOnAddInManifestsDownloadedEvent(IClickOnceAddInInstaller addInInstaller, Uri deploymentManifestUri, AddInInstallationStatus addinSolutionState, String productName, String deploymentManifestXml, String applicationManifestXml, String hostManifestXml, String logFilePath, String version, Uri supportUri)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably can try to clear cache

`rundll32 %windir%\system32\dfshim.dll CleanOnlineAppCache`